# Why was Tisha B'Av established as a day of crying for those who didn't sin?

Tags: reward-punishment, tisha-bav, parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies, masechet-taanis

Ta'anis 29a teaches that since by the Meraglim the Jews cried for naught, that night, which was Tisha B'av, would be established as a night of crying for all generations.

Why should this be? What did their offspring do, that they should be punished? Sure, HaShem visits the sin until the fourth generation (Shemos 20:5)<sup>1</sup>, but the Churban was much more than four generations later.

<sup>1</sup>Makkos 24a notes that this was one of four statements that Moshe said that later prophets overrode. However, at this point in time, it still remained in effect. Perhaps one can argue that at the time of Yechezkel, this statement should be overturned retroactively, which would strengthen this question.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your interpretation. Deciding that a specific day is appropriate to "bundle" punishment for suns is not the same as saying that the children are held liable for the original sin...

Comment: But in the spirit of your question, the resistance toward entering EY at that time created a blemish in our subsequent relationship with the land that ultimately ended until the destruction of at least the first temple and subsequent galus (for failing to uphold Shemittah).